# mongodb datetime filter and aggregation

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, highcharts, timestamp

I have a mongodb qith a collection containng onjects like

```
{ 
    timestamp: <unix timestamp>, 
    sensor: <string>, 
    temperatore: number 
}
```

The full stack is

- Hardware:

  - raspberry pi 3
- Backend:

  - mongodb 2.4.16
  - nodejs 6.8.1
  - mongodn (node module) 2.2.11
- Frontend

  - angularjs 1.5.8
  - highcharts 5
  - highcharts-ng 0.0.13

In my actual setup I have a record every minute, from 3 different sensors, so 4320 records/day. That's fine for charting over 1 day period.

I'd like to find a way to reduce the number of records so charting a period of 1 week is faster and I don't need to send all the 32040 records.

I was thinking about getting one value every 10 minutes (the chart is less precise but I don't need to zoom in), filtered at the node level, but it can get heavy when I'll want to chart i.e. 1 year (1.5M records).

So I'd like to get some opinions on how to do that efficiently. Probably some elaborate filter on the `find()` call, but I can't  think of anything that could work, except migrating to a traditional DB (PostgreSQL or Mariadb).

Comment: You could benefit from a time-series database like [InfluxDB](https://www.influxdata.com/time-series-platform/influxdb/) which interface really well with anything, including [Grafana](http://grafana.org/).

Comment: thanks, O will look into it, I sis not know it existed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution could be to pre-compute the average temperature for an hour/day and save it in an other collection. 
For example, you could have 3 collections :

1. Main collection with all records (1 minute interval) for the day by day graph : 4320 points to display
2. Hour collection storing the average temperature for each half-hour, for the week graph : 1008 points to display
3. Day collection storing the average temperature for each 6 hours, for the year graph: 4380 points to display

and then query a specific collection depending on the precision wanted.

Of course there will be a little redundancy in your data, but the query/display will be way faster

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about this solution too